# Naturality of connecting homomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I'm reading Weibel's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra" page by page. I'm confused about theorem 1.3.1:

> **Theorem 1.3.1** Let $0\to A.\xrightarrow{f} B.\xrightarrow{g}C.\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of chain complexes. Then there are natural maps $\partial:H_n(C)\to H_{n-1}(A)$, called connecting homomorphisms, such that
> \begin{equation}...\xrightarrow{g}H_{n+1}(C)\xrightarrow{\partial}H_n(A)\xrightarrow{f}H_n(B)\xrightarrow{g}H_n(C)\xrightarrow{\partial}H_{n-1}(A)\xrightarrow{f}...
> \end{equation}
> is an exact sequence.

He prove the existence and exactness parts of the theorem by invoking the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem and chasing diagrams and elements. And there is no confusion to me. In Proposition 1.3.4, he explains what the naturality of $\partial$ means:

> **Proposition 1.3.4** The long exact sequence is a functor from $\mathcal{S}$ (category of short exact seuqnces of chain complexes) to $\mathcal{L}$ (category of long exact seuqnces). That is, for every short exact sequence there is a long exact sequence, and for every map of short exact sequences there is a commutative ladder diagram
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{matrix}
> ... \xrightarrow{\partial} & H_n(A)      & \to &H_n(B) & \to & H_n(C)& \xrightarrow{\partial} &H_{n-1}(A) & \to ...\\
>                         & \downarrow  &&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
> ... \xrightarrow{\partial} & H_n(A')      & \to &H_n(B') & \to & H_n(C')& \xrightarrow{\partial} &H_{n-1}(A') & \to ...
> \end{matrix}
> \end{equation}

The proof is here [image]
He still prove the proposition by invoking the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem and chasing diagrams and elements. Here the confusion arise.

**My confusion:** 1. In the proof of Theorem 1.3.1, the connecting homomorphism is canonically constructed in **mod-R**. However, connecting homomorphism is not carnonically construted in the general abelian category. In the proof of Proposition 1.3.4, how can we guarantee that the Freyd-Mitchell embedding functor sends the connecting homomorphisms to the canonically constructed connecting homomorphisms in **mod-R** ?

I'm new to homological algebra. I would be very grateful if you can give me some detailed explanation!

---

EDIT: I have other two questions:

2. Do any choice of connecting homomorphisms that make the sequence in Theorem 1.3.1 exact also make the diagram in Proposition 1.3.4 commute ?
3. Is there a canonical way to choose connecting homomorphisms in a general abelian category to make the Proposition 1.3.4 holds ?

I think these questions are essentially same.

Comment: I know that it doesn't answer your specific question, but: it is important that the embedding theorem is not necessary (and in fact, quite unnatural and clumsy, and your (good!) question demonstrates this) to develop the basics of homological algebra. Specifically, the connecting homomorphism can be constructed from the Snake Lemma (if I recall correctly) and the Snake Lemma can be proven directly from the axioms of an abelian category. See https://www.jstor.org/stable/1993003 and for a generalization to exact categories see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1480.pdf.

Comment: In [my notes](http://zll22.user.srcf.net/writing/homotopical-algebra/2015-11-10-Main.pdf) (lemma 9.1.20) I construct the connecting homomorphism by a kind of degree shift argument and use the embedding only to justify the argument for exactness. However, as Martin says, you can usually do without the embedding theorem, and for this kind of argument there is a standard technique explained in CWM and sometimes called "chasing subobjects".